# How to correctly set "content-disposition" for firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage with cloud functions, and an using

```
firebase.storage().bucket().file('/myvideo.mp4').getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    promptSaveAs: 'myvideo.mp4',
    responseDisposition: 'attachment; filename*=utf-8\'\'myvideo.mp4'
});
```

But, no matter how I switch or change the 2 parameters passed, I always receive

```
inline; filename*=utf-8''myvideo.mp4
```

When navigating to the returned URI. I'm not sure what I've missed in this case.

Comment: `promptSaveAs` is ignored if `responseDisposition` is set: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.3.x/File#getSignedUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone arriving here, I have discovered that no matter how you set these, if there is a `content-disposition` metadata entry on the file in storage, that will always take precedence. This metadata entry is added automatically when uploading through the firebase console.

Comment: Not sure if this is (still) the case. Whether I upload through the Firebase Console, or using the client JavaScript SDKs, the files have the metadata entry Content-Disposition set to `inline; filename*=utf-8''<fileName>`. Creating a download URL with getSignedUrl({ action: "read", promptSaveAs: "file.txt" }) creates a URL that responds with `content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.txt"`